# reading compressed file Gzread using struct c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, gzip

How do read the data a compressed struct format in c++?

here is the data structure..

```
struct test
{
    unsigned int test3;
    unsigned char test1[4096];
    unsigned int test2;
} foo;
```

How do we read the structure written to a file using gzread?

Here is what i've tried.

```
gzread(Handle,&foo.test3, sizeof(&foo.test3)); //64
gzread(Handle,&foo.test1, sizeof(&foo.test1)); //4096
gzread(Handle,&foo.test2,sizeof(&foo.test2)); //4
```

However, the data I get is wrong.
What is the mistake I'm doing?

An example of how to read a file saved in the format of struct would help me do it.

Comment: The size of a pointer will be the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

Comment: and that would be 64, 4096 and 4 in my case. is there anything else i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ok. the rest look fine, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `&foo.test1` you get a pointer, and when you use `sizeof` on that pointer you get the size of the pointer and not what it points to. This will be, depending on platform, either `4` (for 32-bit platforms) or `8` (for 64-bit platforms).

For the code to work, you should drop the use of the `&` operand for the `sizeof` operations:

```
gzread(Handle, &foo.test3, sizeof(foo.test3));
gzread(Handle, &foo.test1, sizeof(foo.test1));
gzread(Handle, &foo.test2, sizeof(foo.test2));
```

However, it *might* still not be correct! What if the file was written to with another order? Or if the complete structure was written in one go, possible padding and all? You need to read it exactly as it was written.

Also, you have to make sure that the file was opened in binary mode, or you might get weird results.

Comment: The complete structure was written in one go!

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: @pistal No, you already know how to call the `gzread` function. You obviously can see the code that writes the structure, it should be very easy for you to figure out how to call `gzread` correctly.

Comment: @pistal That looks good. And you don't have to read the separate fields, the single `gzread` call reads *all* fields.

Comment: How do I access those fields then?

Comment: @pistal Are you talking about accessing them from the code after you read the structure? Then you access them as normal, it's still a normal structure with normal fields. Or are you talking about wanting to read the fields separately *from the file*? In that case it's not needed.

Comment: The first. let me try that.